# android - how to remove darkness from status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-theme

I've darkness in my status bar and I want to remove it . I've removed status and toolbar color to replace it with a gradient color

these are my codes :

```
<style name="AppTheme.TransparentTheme">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
</style>
```

in my code :

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS );
```

the result is this :

Comment: If you want do display your content full screen you should also set View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE flags to. For example, activity.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE.

Comment: @Bracadabra thanks for reply but it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code for that particular screen where you want to remove dark color and also the color you want to show. Place this code after setContentView in that class

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Your_color));

 to change the same color in the navigation bar

window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)
    }
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: thanks for the reply , it works fine , the only problem is that the content is override on the navigation bar , it need to have the navigation too , how to do so ?

Comment: I didnt get you @NavidAbutorab .Can you explain me clearly or with any screenshots please

Comment: check my new edit with the navigation bar color @NavidAbutorab. If it fixes then please accept my answer.

Comment: the problem is that it's in a full screen mode and it takes the full screen height , so the navigation has no places and it comes on the bottom of the layout , the problem is still exists

Comment: You can keep this code in every layout if you want this navigation color @NavidAbutorab

Comment: the problem is the content under the navigation , some part of the layout will be under the navigation bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202139/discussion-between-brahma-datta-and-navid-abutorab).